# Do I need to use the 'using namespace std' command?

Tags: c++, ide, std, cout, cin

I read in the C++ book -> `C++ Programming: Visual Quickstart Guide` that in order to use statements such as `cin` and `cout` without `std::` you need to add the line `using namespace std`.

However at the moment I'm currently doing A-level computer science, using C++ and CBuilder, and I don't have to add that line to my program - since I'm able to use `cout` and `cin` in their own without running into any errors.

Is it not actually needed then? Or does Cbuilder configure `std` itself?

**In short**: Why am I able to skip using std despite having not declared that I'm not using it?

Comment: @NathanOliver no it's not a duplicate - I'm not asking if I should use it, I'm asking why I'm able to skip using `std` despite having not declared that I'm not using it

Comment: Check if `using namespace std;` is defined in any of the header files you are including at your source

Comment: And btw, you can just `using std::cout; using std::cin;`

Comment: "Is it not actually needed then?" It is absolutely needed; see [here](http://ideone.com/slGhaH) for example. Notice the compiler complains that `cout` is undefined and suggests `std::cout` as an alternative. "Or does Cbuilder configure `std` itself?" Maybe, or perhaps maybe one of the header files you are using has the `using namespace std` command in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some compilers/libraries are just more lax with respect to the Standard than others: according to the Standard, your program should not compile. Namespace pollution (putting names into a namespace they don't belong, in this case the global namespace) happens a lot, and leads to these and similar errors when you switch to another compiler and/or standard library.

Unless CBuilder has an option to add an implicit `using namespace std;` to everything it compiles (which would be horrible), the above is all anyone can tell you. There is no "configuring" happening anywhere, not sure what you might mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need that `using` statement. It is an alternative to explicit namespace reference inline within your code. For instance, you can use

```
std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
```

without having a `using` statement.

Or, you could include the `using namespace std` statement and then code:

```
cout << "Hello world" << endl;
```

It's a choice. Personally I prefer to omit the `using` statement and explicitly insert `std::` where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler you use. Some compilers add it for you. But for your own goood and of course knowledge, add `using namespace std;` or you have to put `std::` .